# Rails 3.1- therubyracer gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Using VirtualBox inside of Windows7, it has Ubuntu. Just installed rails 3.1 and getting the following error when I try to bundle install with therubyracer gem.

```
Installing therubyracer (0.9.8) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -I/home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/libv8-3.3.10.2-x86-linux/lib/libv8/v8/include -I/home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/home/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -Wall -g -rdynamic -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -fPIC   -o v8_date.o -c v8_date.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [v8_date.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/therubyracer-0.9.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails311/gems/therubyracer-0.9.8/ext/v8/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing therubyracer (0.9.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.9.8'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> sudo apt-get install g++

Just to be sure, I also recommend:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: Thanks. Thought I was missing a package, just didn't know which one.

Comment: Yes that fixes it. build-essential includes g++ : http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/build-essential